# Internet tethering with iPod Touch 2G

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak, tethering

I have a PC which does not have a build in WLan-Chip. But over the weekend, I'll temporarily move to some place where there is no cable-connection available.

So now I'm trying to find out if I can use tethering to make my iPod's Internet-connection available to my PC (over USB since the PC has no Bluetooth either). I do not have a WLan-adapter or something I could use instead. And since this is only for a few days, I don't want to buy one.

The iPod runs iOS 4.2.1 and is jailbroken. I tried using MyWi 4 to archive this, but when I connect the iPod to the PC (using the USB-cable), nothing happens. The latest iTunes version (10.4) is installed on that PC.

iPhones do have a native tethering-option but this is not available on iPod Touch. Is there any way to activate it (by changing some `.preferences`-files)? I know it's (for example) possible to activate the native multi-tasking that way.

If this is not possible, is there any App out there which works? It seams that MyWi does not work since iTunes 10.1 so is there any other one that works? What do you use?

Comment: What about on a linux computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PdaNet](http://junefabrics.com/iphone/index.php)

Comment: any other apps?? cuz I cant get pdanet on my ipod